# Store an operator in a variable with Ruby

Tags: ruby, operators

Ruby has such beautiful syntactic sugar that I was sure this would work:

```
f = :+
g = 1 f 2 // => 3
```

But, of course, it doesn't.

Is there something similar?  Obviously there are many easy ways around needing to do this, but does Ruby's commitment to amazing sugar extend to doing something like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you can do so with [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) method:

```ruby
f = :+
puts 1.public_send(f, 2) # => 3
```

From docs:

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified. Unlike #send, #public_send calls public methods only.

Comment: "it bypasses visibility checks" – which is why you use `public_send` unless you specifically want to circumvent visibility.

Comment: Thank you @JörgWMittag, I didn't know about this analogue, updated answer